# How to resolve Multi Factor authentication for AAD in Selenium test in CI

Tags: authentication, token, azure-active-directory, adal.js, multi-factor-authentication

I am trying to integrate Selenium tests to CI. The problem I am facing is all the users (even test user) is protected by Multi-factor authentication and when I will run test cases on the server with each login there will a prompt user for the Multi factor. We are running selenium test cases on SPA using adal-angular.js and adal.js
How to resolve this issue? Is there any way to create a logical switch on API server or SPA to bypass the authentication prompt?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this directly. Frankly if you could, I would be very concerned about the security of MFA at all.

Having said that, there is probably a way to help move forward. An SMS Modem (i.e. https://www.diafaan.com/how-to/choose-gsm-modem/) you could register a SIM card with Test User and use the modem to parse the incoming MFA challenge.

Another alternative is to use 3rd pary messaging service (as [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/)) and register a dedicated incoming phone number. Then register that number with the MFA. Then use the Twilio API to parse the MFA challenge.