# How to remove Azure AD MFA for end to end functional automation test

Tags: azure, selenium, asp.net-core, azure-ad-msal, multi-factor-authentication

We have an application protected under Azure AD custom app, using MSAL Library in .NET core MVC web application.
Now we want to automate functional test using Azure CICD pipeline.
When we try to run this automation there is one blocker with MFA where we need to approve manually.

Can I avoid this MFA? I don't want to update conditional access policy as security team already rejected that approach.

Is there a way I can generate the token using secret and then login in to the browser?
How can I bypass the login?

Comment: will you be able to use of app only permission and get your work done ?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread

Comment: App only is to get the data without user permission. My use case is for automation testing where application is ready and I want to login in to browser to access the application without MFA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocking authentication is too much work. We use Azure Key Vault to save user credentials and dynamically get data from Key vault in the pipeline. This is a secure way to use credentials.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot bypass MFA unless you [mock authentication and authorization](https://lukaszcoding.com/2020/04/integration-testing-in-net-core/) which is pretty doable in .NET Core. If you go the selenium route then take a look to H[ow to resolve Multi Factor authentication for AAD in Selenium test in CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48350590/how-to-resolve-multi-factor-authentication-for-aad-in-selenium-test-in-ci), it might help.